# python errorsが引数のtypeerrorに関して

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

「python 実践データ分析100本ノック」のノック66番の生産最適化問題を解く中で
typeerrorが出てしまい止まってしまっております。
エラー文によると'errors'が予期せぬ引数として受け付けられていないようなのですが
修正方法がどう調べてもわからず質問させていただきました。
8行目の処理で↑の問題が発生しているようです。

```
import pandas as pd
from pulp import LpVariable, lpSum, value
from ortoolpy import model_max, addvars, addvals

df = df_material.copy()
inv = df_stock

m = model_max()
v1 = {(i):LpVariable('v%d'%(i),lowBound=0) for i in range(len(df_profit))}
m += lpSum(df_profit.iloc[i]*v1[i] for i in range(len(df_profit)))
for i in range(len(df_material.columns)):
    m += lpSum(df_material.iloc[j,i]*v1[j] for j in range(len(df_profit)) ) <= df_stock.iloc[:,i]
m.solve()

df_plan_sol = df_plan.copy()
for k,x in v1.items():
    df_plan_sol.iloc[k] = value(x)
print(df_plan_sol)
print("総利益:"+str(value(m.objective)))
```

エラー文は下記となります。答えがついているので試しに実行したところ
全く同じコードで自分で試したときのみこちらのエラーが出ております。

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-eb07d530edd3> in <module>
      9 m = model_max()
     10 v1 = {(i):LpVariable('v%d'%(i),lowBound=0) for i in range(len(df_profit))}
---> 11 m += lpSum(df_profit.iloc[i]*v1[i] for i in range(len(df_profit)))
     12 for i in range(len(df_material.columns)):
     13     m += lpSum(df_material.iloc[j,i]*v1[j] for j in range(len(df_profit)) ) <= df_stock.iloc[:,i]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py in lpSum(vector)
   2246     :param vector: A list of linear expressions
   2247     """
-> 2248     return LpAffineExpression().addInPlace(vector)
   2249 
   2250 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py in addInPlace(self, other)
    858                 self.addInPlace(e)
    859         elif isinstance(other, list) or isinstance(other, Iterable):
--> 860             for e in other:
    861                 self.addInPlace(e)
    862         else:

<ipython-input-54-eb07d530edd3> in <genexpr>(.0)
      9 m = model_max()
     10 v1 = {(i):LpVariable('v%d'%(i),lowBound=0) for i in range(len(df_profit))}
---> 11 m += lpSum(df_profit.iloc[i]*v1[i] for i in range(len(df_profit)))
     12 for i in range(len(df_material.columns)):
     13     m += lpSum(df_material.iloc[j,i]*v1[j] for j in range(len(df_profit)) ) <= df_stock.iloc[:,i]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63                     break
     64                 if isinstance(other, cls):
---> 65                     return NotImplemented
     66 
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(left, right)
    341 
    342 
--> 343 def frame_arith_method_with_reindex(left: DataFrame, right: DataFrame, op) -> DataFrame:
    344     """
    345     For DataFrame-with-DataFrame operations that require reindexing,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
    188 
    189     Note: the caller is responsible for ensuring that numpy warnings are
--> 190     suppressed (with np.errstate(all="ignore")) if needed.
    191 
    192     Parameters

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    138 def _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp: bool = False):
    139     """
--> 140     Return the result of evaluating op on the passed in values.
    141 
    142     If native types are not compatible, try coercion to object dtype.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in <module>
     17 from pandas._typing import FuncType
     18 
---> 19 from pandas.core.computation.check import NUMEXPR_INSTALLED
     20 from pandas.core.ops import roperator
     21 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\check.py in <module>
      1 from pandas.compat._optional import import_optional_dependency
      2 
----> 3 ne = import_optional_dependency("numexpr", errors="warn")
      4 NUMEXPR_INSTALLED = ne is not None
      5 if NUMEXPR_INSTALLED:

TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'
```

Comment: 括弧が不足している等の「全く同じコード」では無いのでは？ あるいは以前に実行したりした何かの影響が残って動きが変わっているとか？ 例えば`df_profit`の内容や基となったCSVファイルの内容が変わっているとか？ それぞれのソースコードを良く見較べたり、いったん動作環境をリセットや再起動してクリーンな状態で実行してみるとか試してみてください。

Comment: `import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'` と表示されていますが、Pandas 1.3.1 の `import_optional_dependency()` には `errors` keyword があります。これは [2021/1/11](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/d9ae3080e239ef0d41e6e289cf90230b28a8a5bc#diff-84ea1f1fe219181224e96dbeb1dcac77b46907ba4699ef194e25deffd2c01041) に commit されているので、pandas を最新版にアップデートしてみて下さい。

Comment: @kunif様 早速のご返答ありがとうございます。取り急ぎソースコードの再チェックと動作環境のリセットを実施してみます！

Comment: @metropolis様 ありがとうございます。バージョンの問題だったんですね、、pandasの最新版へのアップデートによって無事解決できました。お手数おかけしてすみません、大変助かりました。